# Как вставить данные в другую таблицу с преобразованием типа данных одного из столбцов?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица, нужно сделать её копию, но изменить тип данных одного столбца:

- id(id) - name(varchar2) - phone(**varchar2**)

Нужно:

- id(id) - name(varchar2) - phone(**number**)

Нужно сохранить данные при копировании. В колонке `phone` данные записаны в таком формате - `34252345`.

Знаю о такой возможности внесения данных:

```
insert into new_table
select * from old_table
```

Но как при этом преобразовать тип данных?

---

В таблице более 3 миллионов записей, так что выгрузить её и залить в новую будет проблематично.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Символьные данные будут неявно преобразованы в числовые. Так как колонка `phone` содержит только целочисленные значения, то каких либо проблем неявное преобразование не вызовет.

```
create table t1 (id, name, phone) as
    select 1, 'name', '34252345' from dual;

create table t2 (id int, name varchar2(8), phone number);

insert into t2
    select * from t1;

1 row inserted.

select * from t2;

        ID NAME          PHONE
---------- -------- ----------
         1 name       34252345
```

---

**Заметка об ограничении ответственности:**
Телефонные номера правильно хранить в колонках с символьным типом данных. Попытка преобразовать их в числовой тип данных являетсся ошибкой дизайна БД, которая может привести к потере данных.

Comment: Расскажите пожалуйста, почему правильней хранить как varchar2? Вроде номера состоят только из цифр. Как я предполагаю с цифрами будет быстрее поиск, в случае если поле не индексируется.

Comment: @Alpensin Как вы собиратесь хранить, например, принятое во многих странах "00" вместо +, т.е. 0079259876543 перевратится в  79259876543? Кроме того, число это всегда 22 байта, телефонный номер в символьном виде обычно занимает меньше места.